# Using dplR, I am attempting to read site, tree, and core IDs from a ring width length data.frame

Tags: r

I am attempting to sort samples based on a 6, and occasionally 7, digit code. I am running into an issue when I have a 7 digit codes.

examples of my naming system:

```
jT1-1A
jT1-1B
iT2-1A
iT2-1B
iT2-2A
iT2-2B
rT2-10A
rT2-10B
```

The first four digits represent the "site", the next digit (sometimes 2 digits) represents the "individual", finally, A or B represents the specimen (most individuals have both A and B). Ultimately, I am attempting to sort and then average the samples that have two specimens.

```
library(dplR)
bb_pixx <- read.tucson('ButteLake_Burn_PIXX_FINAL_DATED.TXT', header = NULL, long = FALSE, encoding = getOption("encoding"), edge.zeros = TRUE)

##Calulate mean across cores in a tree
bb_pixx.ids <- read.ids(bb_pixx, stc = c(4, 1, 1), ignore.site.case = TRUE)
```

How can I write code to account for the occasional 2 digit number?

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "account for" the digit? What exactly doesn't the current code do that you need it to do? Or what output do you need?

Comment: When I use the current code, it is sorting by site just fine(first four digits) then it is only sorting the by the next digit (in which i need it to sort by 2 when my number is two digits, but only one when it is one digit).

Comment: and then finally, sort by A or B, which it is doing already.

Comment: So this is just a question about sorting your raw data?

Comment: So, if i write the code to sort by c(4,2,1), this causes issues when the naming is only 6 characters

Comment: more or less yes.

Comment: Sorry if this isnt very clear, I'm relatively new to R